# Copy and paste data based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro code to copy data from one worksheet (Sheet2) and paste on another worksheet (Sheet1). This works fine. But, I would like to have a condition to determine the location to paste the data in Sheet1. 
The condition is that if the country selected (from a dropdown) in cell A1 in Sheet2, is found in column A in Sheet1 (which has copied data), update (overwrite) that country data with the latest data, else if it is a new country it should paste the new data below the last set of data on Sheet1.

Here's the code I have written until now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F44").Copy
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F44").Copy
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post any picture for your condition because not clear? By adding link to picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `match` function over column A to check if you have the country already or not. if the match return a number, use that to replace the country data, otherwise, it will return an error - catch it and add the data at the end of the sheet.
I'm not sure exactly how your data look from what you've written but that's what you'd want to do in genral.

a general approch would be:
i'm using match to find the row value, and iferror to make sure i don't get an error returned.

```
country = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value 'or where your drop down is
    test = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Match(country, "A:A", 0), -1)
    If test = -1 Then
        'copy to end of sheet
    Else
         *with sheets(Sheet1).cells(rows.value, test).end(xlup).offset(1,0)* 
        'copy to the value in test - it's the row number of the country we are copying now
    End If
```

Comment: Hi Avishay, many thanks for the response. I'm new to VBA, can you help to decipher the code to do this? Also, how do I avoid an error - such that if a country is not already in Sheet1, paste the data on the first empty row?

Comment: i've added a general scheme for it using the function i mentioned above, i left out the exact copying, becuase i'm not sure how exactly it is in you sheets.

Comment: Hi Avishay, many thanks for this. Please see the statement after Else that i'm using. however, it is throwing an out of memory error. Would you know why? Please pardon my limited (or no) knowledge of VBA.

Comment: on what line does the debugger mark when you get the out of memory error? also, if you put in your question an example of the sheet i could help more

Comment: I'm not able to add any pictures because I don't have 10 reputations it says.